# NSMutable array is not replaced with new object

Tags: ios

I have a `NSMutableArray` which is storing int values like this

```
[self.destinationPostionPointer addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
[self.destinationPostionPointer addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

after set of code I am trying to replace the above object with

```
[self.destinationPostionPointer replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

But the `destinationPositionPointer` array is not replacing the object with having integer value 1.

Comment: Did you check memory of your self.destinationPostionPointer? it is allocated or not?

Comment: what do you want? to replace all the values to 1 or replace the value at index 0?

Comment: check if the array is nil. i'm pretty sure it is

Comment: Ya got it... Iam not allocated the space. Thank you very much dude.

Comment: Good Can you please up my comment?

Comment: how to up comment. and i dont have any reputations yet.

Comment: read the http://stackoverflow.com/about part here ;) you cannot upvote yet, but you can accept :)

Comment: You can use Number literals nowadays. instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]` you can just do `@(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating memory to this array. So you need to write this line in your code

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
         self.destinationPositionPointer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you ant to replace all the values which are having value 0 means

```
for(int i=0;i< destinationPostionPointer.count;i++)
{
  if([destinationPostionPointer ObjectAtIndex:0 isequaltostring:@"0")
  {
    [self.destinationPostionPointer replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
  }
}
```